# How to use global properties in flex application descriptor?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'd like to refactor my `adobe flex` application descriptor as follows:

```
<application xmlns="..."> 
    <id>...</id> 
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber> 
    <versionLabel>${versionNumber} - My Label</versionLabel>
</application>
```

Is that possible?

Further, could I also fetch the values from a `application.properties` file and reference it directly withint the `application.xml`?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  It's a really quick thing to test...

Comment: Well I especially don't know how I have to tell the xml to resolve values from a specific `properties` file.